# iOS10 UINavigationButton Position different form iOS9

Tags: ios, frame

I find is different when I set

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelViewButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popCurrentViewController)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelViewButton;
```

**On iOS 10**

[image]

**On iOS 9**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I need to narrow the navigationTitleView

```
#define iOS10Later ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 10.f) 

if(iOS10Later) {navigation.titleView = [[SearchBarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 120, 30)];}
```